# Manga where the MC is followed by a god-like person, then sent him to another world with a kingdom and debt

Tags: story-identification, manga

The MC is a boy who is being followed by a god-like person who gets a kick in seeing the MC suffer. So eventually, he kills the lead and sends him to another world where he is left with a kingdom and debt and is still being followed by said god figure. Currently, the MC is attending some school where all his accomplishments in this world have been given to another noble.